# Compare two json data array objects

Tags: jquery, json

One JSON object contains an array of Ids and one contains array of arrays with id and title in each array. Here are my two JSON data formats....

First JSON Data :

```
json1 : [
        "123",
        "456",
        "789"
]
```

Second JSON Data :

```
json2 : [
    [
        "789",
        "Title3"
    ],
    [
        "456",
        "Title2"
    ],
    [
        "123",
        "Title1"
    ]
]
```

So compare order of IDs of above two JSON data, need to create a new JSON data with title name. So the final JSON should be following like these....

Final Output :

```
[
    'Title1',
    'Title2',
    'Title3'
]
```

Please suggested me.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: can't compare without guidelines for the comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
   <script>

    json1='{"json1":["123","456","789"]}';
    obj1 = JSON.parse(json1);       

    json2='{"json2":[{"789":"Title3"},{"456":"Title2"},{"123":"Title1"}]}';     
    obj2 = JSON.parse(json2);

    var resultArray=[];

    for(i=0;i<obj1['json1'].length;i++)
    {
        id=obj1['json1'][i];

        for(j=0;j<obj2['json2'].length;j++)
        {           
            if(typeof obj2['json2'][j][id] !== "undefined")
            {
                resultArray.push(obj2['json2'][j][id]);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(resultArray);   //FINAL RESULT ARRAY

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this

```
var titleArr = json2.filter(function(x) {
    return json1.indexOf(x[0]) != -1; // checking if the both contain same ids
}).map(function(x) {
    return x[1]; // returns just the second element which is title
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json1 = JSON.parse('["123", "456", "789" ]');

var json2 = JSON.parse('[["789", "Title3"],["456","Title2"],["123","Title1"]]');

var titleArr = []; 

for(var i=0; i<json1.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<json2.length; j++){
        if(json2[j][0] == json1[i])
        titleArr.push(json2[j][1]);
    }
}
```